# How to max out dell laptop internal fans without Alienware Command Center?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, performance, windows-11, fan

On my Dell G15 5511 SE laptop, the main operating system is Windows 11 but quite recently I decided to make a small partition to install Windows 10 on it and make a comparison of performance in terms of gaming.

On Windows 11, the Dell Alienware Command Center is installed by default and the only use I make of this program is selecting the thermal profile:performance and activating G-mode by pressing F9/G on my keyboard.

What G-mode does is, it activates the performance thermal profile if it's not the active profile and it maxes out the internal fans over the CPU and GPU.

Both Windows 11 and Windows 10 are fully debloated and optimized however in Windows 10 I manually installed the Dell Alienware Command Center program but it doesn't work as it requires Windows to be updated.

I do not wish to update Windows 10 and re-bloat it. I can choose the power plan to High Performance which corresponds to the performance thermal profile in AWCC. What is left is to max out the fans.

How can I do that without the AWCC program?

Comment: Under `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Power Options` do you have an "Ultra Performance" profile?

Comment: @spikey_richie No, I have Power Saver, Balanced, and High Performance

Comment: Ok, I would make a new one called whatever you want it to be "super duper awesome mode" or whatever. Then set everything to max, and switch to that power profile. You can do that from `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Power Options\Create a Power Plan`, then `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Power Options\Edit Plan Settings` to change the advanced power settings. The advanced option isn't there on the regular create page, which is annoying.

Answer (score 0):

I would create yourself a new Power plan with a name along the lines of "Ultra Performance", and change the advanced power settings on that to set everything to max. Specifically, you want to set the cooling policy to Active

[image]